# Python 3.x AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groupdict'

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

Being a beginner in python I might be missing out on some kind of basics. But I was going through one of the codes from a project and happened to face this :

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groupdict'

Following is the section of code,re-phrased though,still this does result in the same problem.

```
import re

fmt = (r"\+((?P<day>\d+)d)?((?P<hrs>\d+)h)?((?P<min>\d+)m)?"
       r"((?P<sec>\d+)s)?((?P<ms>\d+)ms)?$")
p = re.compile(fmt)
match = p.search('Total run time: 9h 34m 9s 901ms realtime, 7h 6m 29s 699ms uptime')
try:
    d = match.groupdict()
except IndexError:
    print("exception here")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regular expression functions in Python return `None` when the regular expression does not match the given string. So in your case, `match` is `None`, so calling `match.groupdict()` is trying to call a method on nothing.

You should check for `match` first, and then you also don’t need to catch any exception when accessing `groupdict()`:

```
match = p.search('Total run time: 9h 34m 9s 901ms realtime, 7h 6m 29s 699ms uptime')
if match:
    d = match.groupdict()
```

In your particular case, the expression cannot match because at the very beginning, it is looking for a `+` sign. And there is not a single plus sign in your string, so the matching is bound to fail. Also, in the expression, there is no separator beween the various time values.

Try this:

```
>>> expr = re.compile(r"((?P<day>\d+)d)?\s*((?P<hrs>\d+)h)?\s*((?P<min>\d+)m)?\s*((?P<sec>\d+)s)?\s*(?P<ms>\d+)ms")
>>> match = expr.search('Total run time: 9h 34m 9s 901ms realtime, 7h 6m 29s 699ms uptime')
>>> match.groupdict()
{'sec': '9', 'ms': '901', 'hrs': '9', 'day': None, 'min': '34'}
```

Comment: thanx, i believe the expression was messed up

Answer (score 1):

Here, `match` is evaluating to `None`, which is `NoneType` in python.
Hence, you are getting the error.

You can put a null check to avoid it, like:

```
try:
    if !(match is None):
        d = match.groupdict()
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are the steps to understand the error:

1. *'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groupdict'* means you are calling the method `groupdict()` on an object containing None. Looking at your code, the variable `match` contains 'None'.
2. Where is `match` initialised ? Just before, with `re.search()`.
3. Looking at the documentation for regular expression usage in python: https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/re.html#match-objects So `re.search()` returns a None object, wich is completely normal if the regexp doesn't match your subject string. Then you call a method on this None object without controlling its value.

A solution among other, replace

```
try:
    d = match.groupdict()
except IndexError:
    print("exception here")
```

by

```
if match is not None:
    d = match.groupdict()
else:
    print("re.search() returned None")
```

Answer (score 1):

As `re.search` can return `None` if it fails ([see](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)), you should check the returned result explicitly before proceeding:

```
if match is not None:
    d = match.groupdict()
```